# How select first one digit then 2-2 pair digits in python regex?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, match

I am learning python regex and i have one question, I want to match something like this :

subject : 1234567890

match what i want :  `1 then 234 then 567 then 890`

```
1,234,567,890
```

what i tried :

```
(\d)(\d{3})+
```

not working

```
https://regex101.com/r/AaWroO/1/
```

what are some simple ways (not so complicated regex, because I am not so expert, I am a beginner) to do this thing?

Comment: `re.sub(r'(\d)(?=(\d{3})+$)',r'\1,',your_string)`

Comment: Or, straight Python, `[s[::-1][i:i+n][::-1] for i in range(0,len(s),n)][::-1]` where `s` is your string and `n` is the group size.

Comment: Or, if you truly only need 1 digit then groups of 3, `(^\d|\d\d\d)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use alternation to match a digit after a word boundary or any 3 digits:

```
>>> s = '1234567890'
>>> print re.findall(r'\b\d|\d{1,3}', s)
['1', '234', '567', '890']
```

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `\b\d`: Match a digit after word boundary
- `|`: OR
- `\d{1,3}`: Match any 1 to 3 digits

Comment: This only works for a string that is 1 digit then groups of three.

Comment: @anubhava : i wanted to ask how to master regular expression? like i will able to solve any complicated string issue with regex

Comment: Start with great tutorials on http://www.regular-expressions.info/